# Why is PostSharp disabling debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, postsharp

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2017, I've used PostSharp since version 3 in same solution since VS2012 and debugging just worked. I've recently upgraded PostSharp 5 with VS2017 and no debugging symbols were loaded.

I stumbled on the link between PostSharp and debugging, so I disabled PostSharp for the debug configuration and everything worked like before.

Has there been a change to this behaviour? Is disabling PostSharp the only way to debug?

Comment: Same here, it seems PDB file is not generated. Did you find a solution?

Comment: In project properties, in the PostSharp tab, I disabled PostSharp for the debug configuration. I had hoped there was another way.

Answer (score 3):

Netcore applications use PortablePDB format which isn't supported yet by PostSharp. In order to debug netcore applications, you have to change pdb format to full:

1. In Visual Studio Open project properties
2. Select Build tab
3. Click Advanced... button
4. Select 'Full' from Debugging information dropdown
5. Click OK

After these steps everything worked well for my project which I debug on Windows.

Credits to PostSharp Tech Support: http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/4557-pdb-not-generated-for-net-standard-project